# What does split() function do in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data file with example data

```
Pune|020|WA
```

and so on.

I am loading the data to an RDD and then I run a map function inside which I send a split function. I am expecting the rows to be split by words.
eg.

```
val testRDD = sc.textFile("file.txt");
val splitRDD = testRDD.map(x => x.split("|"))
```

The value I am expecting in newRDD is:

```
Pune
020
WA
```

The value I am getting is - `P,u,n,e,0,2,0,W,A`

Please help explain
Also when I am trying to print the RDD with `splitRDD.foreach(println)`
I am getting the values as

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@19e7bf4a
[Ljava.lang.String;@3dbfa08f
[Ljava.lang.String;@6fc62bf4
[Ljava.lang.String;@3b6fd980
[Ljava.lang.String;@2c3080fc
```

```
val testRDD = sc.textFile("file.txt");
val newRDD = testRDD.map(x => x.split("|"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `split` in Java accepts regular expression. [Pipe character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` has special meaning in the regexex, so in order to make your split work, you'd have to escape pipe:

```
testRDD.map(x => x.split("\\|")) // Pune, 020, WA
```

Your second problem is related to Java's implementation of `toString` for arrays, which is not very helpful.
Easiest way to display content of array would be to just make string out of it with `mkString`:

```
splitRDD.foreach(x => println(x.mkString(", "))
```